# Why is SELECT * from a VIEW executing faster than a SELECT (specific columns) from that same VIEW?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `SQL Server 2012`. I have a `VIEW` called `MyView` and I have 2 `T_SQL` queries which pulls data from that `VIEW`.

Query 1 is very simple and looks as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyView
WHERE StayDate >= '2018-03-01'
```

Above query executes in around 28 seconds and returns 151,000 rows.

Query 2 looks as follows:

```
SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C], [Col D], [Col E]
FROM MyView
WHERE StayDate >= '2018-03-01'
```

Query 2 is taking like an indefinite amount of time to execute. I had to cancel the execution after around 8 minutes!!

My problem is that I need to use Query 2 for a specific task. What is causing this difference in execution time?

The `VIEW` 'MyView' has several joins with other tables and some `CASE` statements built-in. I don't think the issue has to do with the `VIEW` itself, else both queries would have behaved more or less the same way in their execution.

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Could it be a cached result?

Comment: can you view the estimated execution plans for each query?

Comment: You could check the query plans and paste them here. The estimated and actual one. Keep in mind that using `*` might cause your query to not use indexes, even if they are in place and take a look at this [blog article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/07/better-way-select-star/).

Comment: If you are not querying some of the columns, and the optimizer is able to prove that they do not affect the result (neither presence of rows nor their number), it will come up with a different (more lightweight) plan that ignores these columns completely. You probably have a cardinality estimate issue where the server, while coming up with a lightweight plan, believes something is going go be very cheap and it turns out to be not, and the full plan does not attempt to use that unexpectedly expensive thing at all, so the lightweight plan ends up being heavier. Update statistics maybe?

Comment: If the network speed is good, couldn't it be faster to stream all the pages continuously than to retrieve sections if columns are specified?

Comment: I have the same problem, but not with time, but with the results

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query, your code passes to the SQL Query Optimizer. It creates execution plan and caches it to memory pool. When you execute the same query again, it uses that execution plan and retrieves the information way quicker. Sometimes if two queries end up with the same execution plan, they can both use the cached one from the memory pool.

Since the view is nothing more than a stored code (literally the same as you saving and executing an sql file), it is supposed to be used repeatedly. Because of that you can fully expect to have some cached EP for the view.

Alas, this is not the case here.

Comment: And what is the solution? An indexed View?

Comment: Why do you need to execute the query if you have the view? For me the solution is to just use the view - in select, in joins, etc. If you want the query to work quickly, you might try to add index to StayDate column or partition by StayDate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your server decides to take another executionplan for some reason. I don't know the correct solution to this but you should probably update statistics or something.

Here are some examples of workarounds Iv'e used when I've had similar problems:

```
SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C], [Col D], [Col E] 
FROM MyView 
WHERE StayDate >= '2018-03-01'
option(recompile)
```

This will ignore statistics and on the fly calculate a new execution plan which hopefully won't be the slow one

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp 
FROM MyView
WHERE StayDate >= '2018-03-01'

SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C], [Col D], [Col E] 
FROM #temp 
WHERE StayDate >= '2018-03-01'
```

perhaps it will retain the fast execution in the insert statement and then you could extract your data from there which I guess will contain significantly less rows